# Broadcastreceiver components are not allowed to bind to services in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Here is what I am doing:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ConnectivityManager conn = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null
            && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    if (isConnected == true) {

        // initChatHub();
         Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ChatService.class);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Connected", 1000).show();
        serviceIntent.putExtras(intent);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
        context.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Disconnected", 1000).show();
    }
}
```

when network state change then application becomes crash when i data-connection off then there is no Error coming when data connection On then app becomes crash and this Exception coming please suggest me how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Post log cat, not screenshot

Comment: You can try this approach. When you call startservice from BroadcasrReceiver onStartCommand will be called with an intent. Better you put required flag and data in intent and handle it from service.

Comment: same problem, but i found solution: Opt 1: I created an empty Activity (non UI, just onCreate() for Bind service) and finish(). In Broadcast > Start Activity with Bundle (if needed). Problem's resolved.

Opt 2: The same way above options but using an Service instead of Activity. Get event Broadcast > Start a new Service > Bind to existing Service you want to bind.

Answer (score 13):

See here [Context.bindService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29) :

> Note: this method can not be called from a BroadcastReceiver
>   component....

So, use [BroadcastReceiver.peekService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#peekService%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) which return `IBinder` from running Service:

```
 Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ChatService.class);
 context.startService(serviceIntent);
 if (isConnected == true) {
  IBinder binder = peekService(context, new Intent(context, ChatService.class));
  Toast.makeText(context, "Connected", 1000).show();
  if (binder != null){
    mChatService = ((LocalBinder) binder).getService();
        //.... other code here          
  }
}
```

Comment: where we ll apply this code @ρяσѕρєя K  please check my code

Comment: @Edge: instead of `context.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);` code use my answer

Comment: @Edge: why you are calling `bindService` from onRecive method?

Comment: //   context.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection,
//     Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);  Using this code i am able connect Signal R service But it Giving Error  when i use given code

Comment: then comment ` context.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection, // Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); ` line and use my suggest answer in place of line

Comment: then how to bind mservice connection look my final code am going through ur code http://paste.ofcode.org/y8nADrXRExLARn2PGSDMbK

Comment: that is ok But am facing problem how to  bind private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection()   this to service

Comment: @Edge: why you want to ` bind private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() this to service` ? becuase you are able to access service using peekService then no need to use `ServiceConnection`.

Comment: @Edge: as already told you it's not possible to use ServiceConnection and bindService from onRecive method

Comment: OK wait let me check this iwill replay u any ways thnky very much

Comment: am still facing problem to Connection when i use this  //    context.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection,
      Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);   its working fine but crashing when data connection on but working but when i use ur code then there is no Connection establish wid signal R we must have to call private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection or bind

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK
You're doing `peekService(context, new Intent(context, ChatService.class));`. Why didn't you just do `peekService(context, serviceIntent);`?

Comment: I started the connection with the service through the activity and through BroadcastReceiver I was able to hear the service, it worked thanks

Answer (score 13):

The reason Android return this exception is Receiver lifecycle. It may be very short. If receiver binds service, receiver may not exist until result return. see here [Receiver lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

The solution is starting another middle service. Let middle service to bind target service. This middle service can be existed until result return. And receiver can be killed in anytime.

There is another hack solution to skip Android NotAllowException. This exception check Context. If this Context comes from Receiver, then Android return Exception. Change your code

```
context.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

to

```
context.getApplicationContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

This hack solution won't keep receiver's life. If you think the result from binding service is not important. You can use this hack solution to skip NotAllowException.

Answer (score 4):

`Service.bindService()` can not be called from a `BroadcastReceiver component`. I use `Application Context`，it is OK

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call bindService from BroadcastReceiver. The alternate is :

1. Create an Application class (by extending Application class)
2. Create a function for starting and binding of service into you Application class
3. In broadcast receiver get instance of your application class and call function for starting service.

**Sample Code:**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    public void startService(){
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ChatService.class);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Connected", 1000).show();
        serviceIntent.putExtras(intent);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
        context.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
   }
}

// inside onReceive function 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     ConnectivityManager conn = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null
            && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    if (isConnected == true) {
        MyApplication app=(MyApplication)context.getApplicationContext();
            app.initChatService();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Disconnected", 1000).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `initChatService()? Thanks.`

Answer (score 1):

I met same problem, when I was trying to access MQTT client from `BroadcastReceiver` like this:

```
public class BroadcastHelper extends BroadcastReceiver implements MqttCallbackExtended  {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    MqttAndroidClient CLIENT;
    mqtt_helper = new MQTThelper( context ); <--- problem was here
    CLIENT = mqtt_helper.getMqttCLIENT();
    CLIENT.setCallback( this );
    mqtt_helper.MqttConnect();
    }
    //... all other functions omitted
}
```

Then I received `NotAllowException` and `Broadcastreceiver components are not allowed to bind to services` error.

So to solve this I had to pass context to the class where MQTT CLIENT is created and handled like this `context.getApplicationContext()` instead of `context` only.

full line:

`mqtt_helper = new MQTThelper( context.getApplicationContext() );`